# How do I test for the equality of two unordered lists?

Tags: list, rust

I have 2 vectors of structs. What's the best method to know that those lists are the same length and that all elements are in both lists?

`[foo, bar, baz, beh]` is "equal" to `[beh, foo, baz, bar]` but `[beh, foo, baz, bar]` is not "equal" to `[beh, foo, baz, baz]`.

Comment: Related terms: ignoring order (I was searching using that and couldn't find this question)

Comment: What we really want is a Multiset. C++ has that. It requires that you can define Compare (Compare naturally defaults to less).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you know that there can never be duplicates, you can use a set (`HashSet` or `BTreeSet`, depending on your types):

```
use std::{collections::HashSet, hash::Hash};

fn my_eq<T>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> bool
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
{
    let a: HashSet<_> = a.iter().collect();
    let b: HashSet<_> = b.iter().collect();

    a == b
}

fn main() {
    assert!(my_eq(
        &["foo", "bar", "baz", "beh"],
        &["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"]
    ));
    assert!(!my_eq(
        &["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"],
        &["beh", "foo", "baz", "baz"]
    ));
}
```

If you need to handle duplicates, you'll want to count the number of values too:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash};

fn my_eq<T>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> bool
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn count<T>(items: &[T]) -> HashMap<&T, usize>
    where
        T: Eq + Hash,
    {
        let mut cnt = HashMap::new();
        for i in items {
            *cnt.entry(i).or_insert(0) += 1
        }
        cnt
    }

    count(a) == count(b)
}

fn main() {
    assert!(my_eq(
        &["foo", "foo", "baz", "beh"],
        &["beh", "foo", "baz", "foo"]
    ));
    assert!(!my_eq(
        &["foo", "foo", "baz", "beh"],
        &["beh", "foo", "baz"]
    ));
}
```

If you want to be super fancy, you can create a *newtype* that adds this type of equality directly:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash};

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct CustomEq<'a, T: 'a>(&'a [T]);

impl<'a, T> CustomEq<'a, T>
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn count(&self) -> HashMap<&T, usize> {
        let mut cnt = HashMap::new();
        for i in self.0 {
            *cnt.entry(i).or_insert(0) += 1
        }
        cnt
    }
}

impl<'a, T> PartialEq for CustomEq<'a, T>
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.count() == other.count()
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        CustomEq(&["foo", "bar", "baz", "beh"]),
        CustomEq(&["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"])
    );
    assert_ne!(
        CustomEq(&["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"]),
        CustomEq(&["beh", "foo", "baz", "baz"])
    );
}
```

Comment: This assumes that elements are either Hash (or Ord, although this is not shown). That's probably true most of the time, but the question does not say that Hash (or Ord) can be used.

Comment: They give you the answer and the tests, what a model answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you have ownership or mutability of your lists, you can sort them and then compare the lists:

```
fn eq_lists_inplace<T>(a: &mut [T], b: &mut [T]) -> bool
where
    T: PartialEq + Ord,
{
    a.sort();
    b.sort();

    a == b
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "beh"];
    let mut b = ["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"];

    assert!(eq_lists_inplace(&mut a, &mut b));

    let mut c = ["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"];
    let mut d = ["beh", "foo", "baz", "baz"];

    assert!(!eq_lists_inplace(&mut c, &mut d));
}
```

If you don't have ownership, then you could take references to the items and sort those:

```
fn eq_lists<T>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> bool
where
    T: PartialEq + Ord,
{
    let mut a: Vec<_> = a.iter().collect();
    let mut b: Vec<_> = b.iter().collect();
    a.sort();
    b.sort();

    a == b
}

fn main() {
    let a = &["foo", "bar", "baz", "beh"];
    let b = &["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"];
    assert!(eq_lists(a, b));

    let c = &["beh", "foo", "baz", "bar"];
    let d = &["beh", "foo", "baz", "baz"];
    assert!(!eq_lists(c, d));
}
```

There are various ways of sorting available to you. A sample of alternates:

- [`sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_key)
- [`sort_unstable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid use of a Hash, you can:

- Iterate over the elements in one list
- Remove an item in the other if it is matched
- Then check that the match count is equal to the length of the lists.

Here I have implemented it as a trait on `Vector<T>`:

```
trait UnorderedEq {
    fn unordered_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool;
}

impl<T: Eq + Clone> UnorderedEq for Vec<T> {
    fn unordered_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        if self.len() != other.len() {
            return false;
        }

        let mut match_count = 0;

        let mut other_to_check: Self = Vec::new();
        other_to_check.clone_from(other);

        for item in self {
            let index_in_other = other_to_check.iter().position(|e| e == item);

            if let Some(index) = index_in_other {                
                other_to_check.remove(index);
                match_count += 1;
            }
        }

        self.len() == match_count
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn ordered_eq() {
        assert!(vec![0, 1].unordered_eq(&vec![0, 1]));
    }

    #[test]
    fn unordered_eq() {
        assert!(vec![2, 1, 0].unordered_eq(&vec![0, 1, 2]));
    }

    #[test]
    fn wrong_len_not_eq() {
        assert!(!vec![0, 1].unordered_eq(&vec![0, 1, 2]));
        assert!(!vec![0, 1, 2].unordered_eq(&vec![0, 1]));
    }

    #[test]
    fn empty_eq() {
        let vec_1: Vec<usize> = vec![];
        let vec_2: Vec<usize> = vec![];
        assert!(vec_1.unordered_eq(&vec_2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have for when you're comparing:

- Iterators of structs that implement PartialEq
- Do not have ownership of the iterators

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Dog {
    species: String,
    age: u32
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Cat {
    species: String,
    age: u32
}

pub struct Pets {
    dogs: Vec<Dog>,
    cats: Vec<Cat>
}


impl Pets {
    fn is_equal(&self, other_pets: &Pets) -> bool {

        // If self has any Dog that is not in other_pets, or if self.dogs.len != other_pets.dogs.len(), return false
        if self.dogs.iter().any(|dog| !other_pets.dogs.contains(dog)) || self.dogs.len() != other_pets.dogs.len() {
            return false;
        }

        // If self has any Cat that is not in other_pets, or if self.cats.len != other_pets.cats.len(), return false
        if self.cats.iter().any(|cat| !other_pets.cats.contains(cat)) || self.cats.len() != other_pets.cats.len() {
            return false;
        }

        // Checks passed, return true
        true
    }
}
```